# Python: how can I change amount_sold and price_per_unit from string to int

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

**I want to change amount_sold and price_per_unit from string to int but its error. After I zipped the data, each attribute becomes a tuple. Then, I try to change to list by using this code (list(amount_sold)) but it resulting in an error**

```
path = 'data.txt'   
f = open(path)        

for line in f:       
pass          

data = [line.rstrip('\n').split(' ') for line in open(path)]      
data      


> output
[['2020-09-23', 'Item_A', '5', '1.90'],
['2020-09-23', 'Item_B', '6', '1.20'],
['2020-09-23', 'Item_A', '2', '1.90'],
['2020-09-23', 'Item_B', '3', '1.20'],
['2020-09-24', 'Item_A', '13', '1.90'],
['2020-09-24', 'Item_B', '2', '1.20'],
['2020-09-24', 'Item_C', '8', '1.30'],
['2020-09-25', 'Item_D', '7', '2.70'],
['2020-09-25', 'Item_A', '15', '1.90'],
['2020-09-25', 'Item_D', '7', '2.70'],
['2020-09-25', 'Item_B', '6', '1.20'],
['2020-09-26', 'Item_B', '1', '1.20'],
['2020-09-26', 'Item_C', '8', '1.30'],


date, item_name, amount_sold, price_per_unit = zip(*data)    
int(date)    


>I get an error at this line that is TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: share the contents of your `data.txt`, it is possible to recreate that with `output` but for completion sake

Comment: please remove the back-tics from your code, they aren't needed

Comment: what is `line_list`? - Is that `data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've got this right because you don't explain what `line_list` is.  However, it seems reasonable to assume that `line_list == data`.  Making that assumption, reconstructing your data from the output you give, using your line of code with the `zip` call, and then doing what you're asking about in your subject, I don't have a problem.  Your code seems pretty right on to me.  Here's what I did with your code:

```
data = [['2020-09-23', 'Item_A', '5', '1.90'],
['2020-09-23', 'Item_B', '6', '1.20'],
['2020-09-23', 'Item_A', '2', '1.90'],
['2020-09-23', 'Item_B', '3', '1.20'],
['2020-09-24', 'Item_A', '13', '1.90'],
['2020-09-24', 'Item_B', '2', '1.20'],
['2020-09-24', 'Item_C', '8', '1.30'],
['2020-09-25', 'Item_D', '7', '2.70'],
['2020-09-25', 'Item_A', '15', '1.90'],
['2020-09-25', 'Item_D', '7', '2.70'],
['2020-09-25', 'Item_B', '6', '1.20'],
['2020-09-26', 'Item_B', '1', '1.20'],
['2020-09-26', 'Item_C', '8', '1.30']]

date, item_name, amount_sold, price_per_unit = zip(*data)

print(amount_sold)

x = list(amount_sold)
print(x)
```

Result:

```
('5', '6', '2', '3', '13', '2', '8', '7', '15', '7', '6', '1', '8')
['5', '6', '2', '3', '13', '2', '8', '7', '15', '7', '6', '1', '8']
```

As you can see, I get a tuple for `amount_sold` just like you say.  But I can turn it into a `list` even though you say you get an error when you do this.

If you can see what you're doing different than what's going on here, maybe it will help you to figure out what's going on.  I don't see by looking at your code, how you would be getting an error like `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`.  I'm curious why that is coming up for you.

I figure you probably already know this, but you can turn your lists of strings into lists of numbers with an expression like this:

```
amount_sold = [int(x) for x in amount_sold]
print(amount_sold)
```

Result:

```
[5, 6, 2, 3, 13, 2, 8, 7, 15, 7, 6, 1, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output = [['2020-09-23', 'Item_A', '5', '1.90'],
['2020-09-23', 'Item_B', '6', '1.20'],
['2020-09-23', 'Item_A', '2', '1.90'],
['2020-09-23', 'Item_B', '3', '1.20'],
['2020-09-24', 'Item_A', '13', '1.90'],
['2020-09-24', 'Item_B', '2', '1.20'],
['2020-09-24', 'Item_C', '8', '1.30'],
['2020-09-25', 'Item_D', '7', '2.70'],
['2020-09-25', 'Item_A', '15', '1.90'],
['2020-09-25', 'Item_D', '7', '2.70'],
['2020-09-25', 'Item_B', '6', '1.20'],
['2020-09-26', 'Item_B', '1', '1.20'],
['2020-09-26', 'Item_C', '8', '1.30']]

new_output = [[a,b,int(c), float(c)] for a,b,c,d in output]

# normal print
print(new_output)

# pretty print
from pprint import pprint
pprint(new_output)

# wordy print
for _date, item_name, amount_sold, price_per_unit in new_output:
    print(f"Date: {_date}, Item: {item_name}, "
          f"Amount Sold: {amount_sold}, Price Per Unit: {price_per_unit}")
```

This will do the trick. If you want to deal with larger datasets, I would suggest you invest some time learning to use the Pandas library.

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer as correct when you get a chance.